# Grails url mapping passing data from sperate config file

Tags: grails

I have a project for hospitals which is planned for more than 10 hospitals and all these hospitals  has to access the project from url like www.mydomain.com:8080/xxxxx/hospitalproject/login/auth   where xxxxx will be their hospital names and how should i manage them in url mapping.groovy   or  is thier any idea to pass them from a sperate file 
please help me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only need one instance of your application for all hospitals what you need is to set up a reverse proxy, 
that will handle incoming requests for each hospital specific url path and redirect to your application url.
Some links that might help you

http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/configure-mod_proxy_ajp-with-tomcat/start

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html